# I have used TagListControl from FerretLib.WinForms but I have a problem with event handler

Tags: c#, winforms

I tried many ways for handling event for enter on the TagListControl but didnt work
I tried Click and Enter and I tried by manual Like TagListControl.KeyPress + = .....

I put it in a group box I thought if I tried handle event click for group box. i do not know

anyone can help me? please

Comment: Make an event handler for radio button change.  You can make one handle for all buttons.  Then in handler read name of button so you do not need an event for each button

Comment: Please give a minimal example that reproduces your issue

Comment: I'm using this tool that the link is below, I need make event for adding and removing tag  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=T1MVZxTvI-w